# strcpy behaving differently when two pointers are assigned strings in different ways

Tags: c

I am sorry, I might me asking a dumb question but I want to understand is there any difference in the below assignments? strcpy works in the first case but not in the second case.

```
char *str1;
*str1 = "Hello";
char *str2 = "World";
strcpy(str1,str2);    //Works as expected
```

---

```
char *str1 = "Hello";
char *str2 = "World";
strcpy(str1,str2);    //SEGMENTATION FAULT
```

How does compiler understand each assignment?Please Clarify.

Comment: You should either use `char str1[] = "Hello";` or allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: Your first example does not even compile, should be `str1 = "Hello";`. Having said that, it is UB to modify a string literal.

Comment: Hello Vane, first example compiles and works as expected on my cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both code are wrong, even if "it works" in your first case. Hopefully this is only an academic question! :)

First let's look at `*str1` which you are trying to modify.

```
char *str1;
```

This declares a dangling pointer, that is a pointer with the value of some unspecified address in the memory. Here the program is simple there is no important stuff, but you could have modified very critical data here!

```
char *str = "Hello";
```

This declares a pointer which *will* point to a protected section of the memory that even the program itself cannot change during execution, this is what a segmentation fault means.

To use strcpy(), the first parameter should be a char array dynamically allocated with malloc(). If fact, don't use strcpy(), learn to use strncpy() instead because it is safer.

Comment: I would advise the OP to learn **not to use** `strncpy()`.  write your own function that copies a string but clip it to the destination buffer size.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, both examples are very wrong and lead to undefined behaviour, that might or might not crash. Let me try to explain why:

- `str1` is a dangling pointer. That means `str1` points to *somewhere* in your memory, writing to `str1` can have arbitrary consequences. For example a crash or overriding some data in memory (eg. other local variables, variables in other functions, everything is possible)
- The line `*str1 = "Hello";` is also wrong (even if `str1` were a valid pointer) as `*str1` has type `char` (*not* `char *`) and is the first character of `str1` which is dangling. However, you assign it a pointer (`"Hello"`, type `char *`) which is a type error that your compiler will tell you about
- `str2` is a valid pointer but presumably points to read-only memory (hence the crash). Normally, constant strings are stored in read-only data in the binary, you *cannot* write to them, but that's exactly what you do in `strcpy(str1,str2);`.

A more correct example of what you want to achieve might be (with an array on the stack):

```
#define STR1_LEN 128
char str1[STR1_LEN] = "Hello"; /* array with space for 128 characters */
char *str2 = "World";
strncpy(str1, str2, STR1_LEN);
str1[STR1_LEN - 1] = 0; /* be sure to terminate str1 */
```

Other option (with dynamically managed memory):

```
#define STR1_LEN 128
char *str1 = malloc(STR1_LEN); /* allocate dynamic memory for str1 */
char *str2 = "World";
/* we should check here that str1 is not NULL, which would mean 'out of memory' */
strncpy(str1, str2, STR1_LEN);
str1[STR1_LEN - 1] = 0; /* be sure to terminate str1 */
free(str1); /* free the memory for str1 */
str1 = NULL;
```

**EDIT:** @chqrlie requested in the comments that the `#define` should be named `STR1_SIZE` not `STR1_LEN`. Presumably to reduce confusion because it's not the length in characters of the "string" but the length/size of the buffer allocated. Furthermore, @chqrlie requested not to give examples with the `strncpy` function. That wasn't really my choice as the OP used `strcpy` which is very dangerous so I picked the closest function that can be used correctly. But yes, I should probably have added, that the use of `strcpy`, `strncpy`, and similar functions is not recommended.

Comment: It a error prone to name a size `STR1_LEN`, you should call this `STR1_SIZE` or allocate `STR1_LEN+1` bytes. It is bad advice to encourage the use of braindead `strncpy()`. It does not do what most programmers think, and tends to cause errors and inefficiencies.

Comment: @chqrlie `STR1_SIZE` might indeed be the better name. However, `LEN` isn't wrong, it's just not the "string length" but the "buffer length".
Also: I did not choose to use `strcpy`, that was in the OPs question. I then went for `strncpy` because it's at least correct. Obviously you should still probably avoid it.

Comment: The OP might not have known about `strncpy()`, he should learn to avoid it.  It is only half correct, and you know how to correct the confusing misfeature in case the buffer is too short.  But did you know `strncpy()` will pad `str1` with `NUL` bytes to the size specified if larger than the source string length?  `snprintf(str1, STR1_SIZE, "%s", str2);` is inefficient too, but at least does the job.  I usually define a utility function in my projects that does just that, similar to BSD's `strlcpy()` but with a different argument order.

Comment: @chqrlie, sure, `strncpy` does always copy the number of bytes specified, if it's short of input it'll add `\0` bytes. What's the problem? This questions isn't about efficiency at all! And it runs _always in the same amount of time_, that's not really inefficient. For jobs like what the OP wants, you'd usually use `char *str1 = strdup(str2); ...; free(str1);`. But I wanted to stay as close to the question as possible (without being obviously wrong and using `strcpy`).

Comment: OK, I am a bit anal about this stupid function that was originally designed to fill user database entries in binary files.  I think it is our job to teach OPs good practices and useful idioms and warn them about error prone APIs.  So much confusion arises daily from newbies misusing pointers, `scanf()`, `feof()` etc.

Comment: @chqrlie StackOverflow is not an evangelising platform. People ask questions and other people reply _to the question_. Obviously, it's acceptable to add examples how this could be improved but the main point is to answer the question. And I think I did that. I told the OP what the problems are (undefined behaviour) and as a bonus added a correct solution which is very close to the original.

Comment: The rationale for `strncpy()` is here: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/d11.html .  Regarding answering questions, I believe good answers should of course respond to the question, but also teach both the OP and the readers something useful in the context of the question. 授人以鱼不如授人以渔

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: In the first snippet you wrote `*str1 = "Hello"` which is equivalent to assigning to `str[0]`, which is obviously wrong, because `str1` is uninitialized and therefore is an invalid pointer. If we assume that you meant `str1 = "Hello"`, then you are still wrong:

According to C specs, *Attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior: they may be stored in read-only storage (such as .rodata) or combined with other string literals* so both snippets that you provided will yield undefined behavior.

I can only guess that in the second snippet the compiler is storing the string in some read-only storage, while in the first one it doesn't, so it works, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Unless the OP mistyped the question, the first code should not even compile.

Comment: @chqrlie According to specs, it probably shouldn't. But it does - https://ideone.com/tYN3Lj - however, as I said, some compilers (probably such as OP's) may not place string in read-only storage, which may explain why it works for OP.

Comment: Re-read the code: `*str1 = "Hello";` is trying to assign the pointer to the `char` pointed to by `str1`, which does uninitialized.

Comment: @chqrlie Oops, you are absolutely correct. The runtime error happens for the `*str1 = "Hello"` and not the `strcpy`.

Comment: It is a shame that such mistakes are only flagged by the compiler with a confusing warning `warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [6]'`, and only so if warnings are explicitly requested (`clang -Wall`).  Of course, the `strcpy()` is also a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion here. Both fragments invoke undefined behaviour. Let me explain why:

- `char *str1;` defines a pointer to characters, but it is uninitialized.  It this definition occurs in the body of a function, its value is invalid.  If this definition occurs at the global level, it is initialized to `NULL`.
- `*str1 = "Hello";` is an error: you are assigning a string pointer to the character pointed to by `str1`.  `str1` is uninitialized, so it does not point to anything valid, and you channot assign a pointer to a character.  You should have written `str1 = "Hello";`.  Furthermore, the string `"Hello"` is constant, so the definition of `str1` really should be `const char *str1;`.
- `char *str2 = "World";`  Here you define a pointer to a constant string `"World"`.  This statement is correct, but it would be better to define `str2` as `const char *str2 = "World";` for the same reason as above.
- `strcpy(str1,str2); //Works as expected`  **NO it does not work at all!**  `str1` does not point to a `char` array large enough to hold a copy of the string "World" including the final `'\0'`. Given the circumstances, this code invokes undefined behaviour, which may or may not cause a crash.

You mention the code *works as expected*: it only does no in appearance: what really happens is this: `str1` is uninitialized, if it pointed to an area of memory that cannot be written, writing to it would likely have crashed the program with a segmentation fault; but if it happens to point to an area of memory where you can write, and the next statement `*str1 = "Hello";` will modify the first byte of this area, then `strcpy(str1, "World");` will modify the first 6 bytes at that place. The string pointed to by `str1` will then be "World", as expected, but you have overwritten some area of memory that may be used for other purposes your program may consequently crash later in unexpected ways, a very hard to find bug!  This is definitely *undefined behaviour*.

The second fragment invokes undefined behaviour for a different reason:

- `char *str1 = "Hello";` No problem, but should be `const`.
- `char *str2 = "World";` OK too, but should also be `const`.
- `strcpy(str1,str2); //SEGMENTATION FAULT` **of course it is invalid**: you are trying to overwrite the constant character string `"Hello"` with the characters from the string `"World"`.  It would work if the string constant was stored in modifiable memory, and would cause even greater confusion later in the program as the value of the string constant was changed. Luckily, most modern environemnts prevent this by storing string constants in a read only memory. Trying to modify said memory causes a segment violation, ie: you are accessing the data segment of memory in a faulty way.

You should use `strcpy()` only to copy strings to character arrays you define as `char buffer[SOME_SIZE];` or allocate as `char *buffer = malloc(SOME_SIZE);` with `SOME_SIZE` large enough to hold what you are trying to copy plus the final `'\0'`

Comment: I agree with you chqrlie. But somehow on Cygwin, the code works as mentioned in the OP. It seems to be more compiler specific. Thanks to all who taught initializing strings in a proper way.

Comment: @Megatron: the consequences of undefined behaviour are compiler and environment specific, among other circumstances that vary from one invokation to the other.  I modified my answer to give you a hint at why it may seem to *behave as expected*.